# Creating docker container with HP UX and IBM AIX

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Can i create a docker container with HP UX and IBM AIX, if so please let me know how to do it?

I tried by creating container from HP UX tar, it got created and i got conatiner id **but unable to login in to the container.**

Let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is there any update on this, i want to run aix based container in docker

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the FAQ https://docs.docker.com/faq/ you will see as supported 
    Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04 et al
    Fedora 19/20+
    RHEL 6.5+
    Centos 6+
    Gentoo
    ArchLinux
    openSUSE 12.3+
    CRUX 3.0+
This github issue is closed at the moment https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3546 but that could change. What you try to do is not supposed to work at the moment (which says nothing about the technical possibility)

Comment: I think my question has been mis interpreted.I am not installing Docker on HP UX or IBM AIX. I have ubuntu 14.04 machine on which docker is installed now i want to create a docker container with HP UX  or IBM AIX OS. Is it possible ?? if so how??

Comment: You want to create a Dockerfile with `FROM HP-UX` or `FROM AIX` see https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from so you need a Linux base image, and in fact, on the hub https://hub.docker.com/ you can find Ubuntu, CentOs, Debian... base images, but no Unix base images.  Docker is only about Linux, but you may have noticed that Solaris has something similar (zones) and FreeBSD too (the jails). See https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#the-underlying-technology if HP-UX or AIX has all (namespaces, control groups, union file systems, container format) it may work.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM developerWorks site has a guide on how to do this, I'm currently doing similar work on Z at the moment.

[Docker on POWER at developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/d-docker-on-power-linux-platform/)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is impossible to build AIX and HP-UX docker containers because the AIX and HP-UX are totally different operation systems with differently build closed SystemV kernels running only on RISC based CPU's compared to the wide spread Linux distributions running on almost everything.

If you have applications that only runs on AIX or HP-UX but you want them in a container, AIX has the option of using Workload Partitions, which is almost comparable with containerization.